# How to get the value of an array after first index?

Tags: php, arrays, implode

I have an **array** which contains the full name. I know how to display the last name which basically resides in the 1st index. How can I display the rest of the values after the last name?

```
$fullname = array('fullname' => 'POTTER Harry James');
$res = implode("", $fullname);
$name = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $res);
$lname = $name[0];
```

What i did in the first name:

```
$fname = $name[1]. " ".$name[2];
```

It works fine, but is there a cleaner way to do that? I mean, what if the user has more than 2 first names?

Thanks.

Comment: Please, consider bottom part of my answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fullname = array('fullname' => 'POTTER Harry James');
$firstNames = strstr($fullname['fullname'], ' '); // $firstNames='Harry James'
```

This gets the string **after** the first space character.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) function:

```
<?php
$fullname = array('fullname' => 'POTTER Harry James');
$parts    = explode(' ', $fullname['fullname']);

var_dump($parts);
?>
```

Shows:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "POTTER"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "Harry"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "James"
}
```

---

You might use any part of `$parts` in a way, that you need.

```
<?php
$a = array_shift($parts);
$b = implode(' ', $parts);

echo "{$b} ({$a})"; // Harry James (POTTER)
?>
```

---

***UPDv1:***

In your current code, you might do just the same thing:

```
<?php
$lname = array_shift($name);
$fname = implode(' ', $name);
?>
```

Comment: +1 from me. Because this is the easiest way to split other than used in Question.

Comment: @CORRUPT: explode won't work. i have tried it countless of times. the problem is that the 2nd parameter should be a string.

Comment: @ladybug , works for me. Just check it. Second argument is a string already. And it should be faster, that your approach (less function calls).

Comment: @ladybug i think approach in answer is better then regx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags :)

Comment: @CORRUPT: thanks for taking time answering my question. appreciate it.

Comment: @CORRUPT: The use of array_shift made more sense, since some of the names have salutations.

Comment: @ladybug: yes it did,  indeed, just tweaked it a bit and viola, just what i needed. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should take out the last name off the array first, then use a loop to concatenate the remaining names as fistname.

```
$fullname = array('fullname' => 'POTTER Harry James');
$res = implode("", $fullname);

$name = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $res);

$lname = array_shift($name);

$fname = "";

foreach($name as $fnames)
    $fname.= " ".$fnames;
```

Comment: I think other answers are simpler.

Comment: @Ziarno still, this answer is correct too. Working, at least.

Comment: Well the question was actually *is there a cleaner way to do that?* imo using regex is not necessary here.

Comment: @Ziano Yes, you're right, there are **cleaner solutions** to the problem

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
<?php
$fullname = array('fullname' => 'POTTER Harry James');
list($lname,$fname) = explode(" ", $fullname["fullname"],2);
echo $fname."<br>".$lname;
?>
```

This will work if the name contains 2 words or more. In case there are more than 2 words then anything except the first word will be considered as first name and first word will be considered as the last name.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of an impossible task. If left to their own devices, users are going to put all sorts of stuff into a single field.

If you care about separating the first and last names of your users, you should ask for them separately, as there is no regex that can possibly determine the correct way to break up their name.